# Multiple while loop in two queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 queries.
and 2 while loops.

my problem is that When I call out the values. only one query and one loop is correct. the other loop is displaying duplicate values.

here is what I have :

```
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2");

while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
  while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){

  echo  $row1['nameofattribute']  ;
  echo  $row2['nameofattribute']  ;
  }
}
```

the output of query 1 is correct. but the output of query 2 is duplicate values.
for example : 
query 1= $row1=2 $row1=3 $row1=4
query 2= $row2=3 $row2=3 $row2=3

instead it should be 
query 1= $row1=2 $row1=3 $row1=4
query 2= $row2=1 $row2=2 $row2=3

on top is my simple translation of the code. here is my real code :

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT remarks FROM passed_deliverable WHERE user_id=$uid && deliverable_category_id=4");

    $query2=mysql_query("SELECT 
    deliverable_id, deliverable_title, deliverable_desc, adviser_id ,deliverable_category_id
    FROM deliverable d
    WHERE d.deliverable_category_id=4
    &&  EXISTS (
    SELECT 'X'
    FROM passed_deliverable pd 
    WHERE pd.deliverable_id = d.deliverable_id && user_id='".$_GET['edit']."' && adviser_id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ) ");

    while($x=mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
    while($deliverable=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){


    echo "
    {$deliverable['deliverable_desc']}
    {$x['remarks']}  
    ";
```

Comment: Did you try JOIN statements

Comment: @IndraKumarS no. im trying to be as simple as possible. but im open to suggestions.

Comment: What are you trying to Achieve?

Comment: @IndraKumarS i edit my question. it is located at the last part of the question.

Comment: You have not posted full code it seems.....

Comment: What is the link between two queries Why did you a while inside while loop

Comment: Your loops make no sense... you interate evertime over the same values... when you want to do that you have to seek and reset your query. Otherwise you get wrong results. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

Comment: You don't use $row2 in echo but two times $row1['nameofattribute'].

Comment: @Stony any suggestion in my loop?

Comment: @MarkYu Do you understand the while loop or not ??????? For every row returned by query1 You running a while loop with query2.. Suppose Query1 returns two rows means.., While fetching the first row, You second query will be called in and looped over. For second row also It will call query2 and return duplicate results.... Thats why i asked what is the link and why do you want second While ?

Comment: im querying out two tables at the sametime. ill post my full code at my question.

Comment: Please read http://php.net/manual/control-structures.while.php. For every value of your first while loop you try to get all values of the second while loop, but when you get the second value of the first while loop the second while is already at the end of possible sql data and will not return anything else.

Comment: im open to suggestions. @hellcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :
other answer or loop from mr. hellcode
it shows that you can also use array values instead of just using array

```
$a1 = 0[];
$a2 = 0[];
while($x=mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
$a1[] = $x['remarks'];
}
 while($deliverable=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
     $a2[] = $deliverable['deliverable_desc'];
}
for($i=0; $i < count($a1) and $i < count($a2); $i++) {
echo "\n\n".$a2[$i]."\n".$a1[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you just want to combine the resulting rows of both tables in their appearing order (ignoring results that exceed the other table):

```
$a1 = array();
$a2 = array();
while($x=mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
    $a1[] = $x['remarks'];
}
while($deliverable=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
    $a2[] = $deliverable['deliverable_desc'];
}
for($i=0; $i < count($a1) and $i < count($a2); $i++) {
    echo "\n\n".$a2[$i]."\n".$a1[$i];
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sir, thank you sooo much! a new lesson learned for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[Deprecation of mysql_ functions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) . Please avoid mysql_ function .   Anyway your query seems to unusual. because we don't see any `WHERE` clause in your queries . That means it will return duplicate value. `Table1` each row will be check all rows  of `Table2` .